# MongoDB find_one on array field returning document every-time even without a match

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, pymongo

Trying so that I can check if a user has previously liked a recipe so they can't like it twice.
I have users in my DB that look like:

```
username:"username"
password:"password"
likes:Array
0:"recipe_id"
```

Im trying to use the query:

```
 if mongo.db.users.find_one({'username': session.get('USERNAME')}, {'likes': [recipe_id]}) == None:
            mongo.db.recipe.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(recipe_id)}, {
                '$inc': {'likes': 1}})
            mongo.db.users.update_one({'username': session['USERNAME']}, {
                '$push': {'likes': recipe_id}})
```

but its just returning regardless of the `recipeId` being in the array or not. I think this is because its doing two queries. Is there a way to specify the second query to only look at that specific user ?

Comment: How about toggling the like button's state? The approach is, if the user has already liked the recipe, then he can only unlike it, else the user can like it.

Comment: thats a good point i didnt think of. Done it now anyway with queries but thank you for contributing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with your query is you're having `likes : [recipe_id]` in projection part of `.find_one`. So it has to be in filter part, Basically second argument to `.find()` or `.find_one()` is projection which helps to project certain fields in the document.

**Try this query :**

```
/** So all you need is to check if `recipe_id` exists in `likes` array or not,
 * then if it exists instead of returning entire doc, 
 * using projection just return `_id` of doc which is quiet enough for your need,
 * in other case query will return none if no matching doc exists */

if mongo.db.users.find_one({'username': session.get('USERNAME'), 'likes': recipe_id}, {_id :1}) == None:
            mongo.db.recipe.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(recipe_id)}, {
                '$inc': {'likes': 1}})
            mongo.db.users.update_one({'username': session['USERNAME']}, {
                '$push': {'likes': recipe_id}})
```

In `.find_one()` you don't need to wrap `recipe_id` in array like what you're doing : `likes : [recipe_id]` is not needed, If you wanted to do it you need to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) operator like this `{ likes : {$in : [recipe_id] } }` in filter part of query.

**Ref :** [.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html) & [.find_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find_one#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)

Comment: Thank you very much! so which is the filter part of the query?

Comment: @MatthewCasey : first arg to `.find_one()` : `.find_one({},{})`